# How to block all file extensions of certain types on nginx

Tags: nginx

I run a number of websites behind an nginx frontend. All my sites are in Python/Django. I see in my logs lots of crawling by hackers for various php applications - I'd like to block them (return a 404) at nginx without them hitting my application servers.

I'd like to do this globally in my nginx conf file so it applies to all my site-specific configurations.

So, how do I:

1. Return 404 for all extensions of type .php
2. Return 404 for partial matches of certain strings, such as "phpmyadmin"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try:

```
location ~ (\.php$|myadmin) {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: gr8 thanks. I accepted this answer because it solves my actual problem, but the addition by alexander below is critical to the way I did want to implement the solution.

Answer (score 7):

`location` must appear inside `server` only, it's not allowed inside `http`.

So, the only option is to create a file with your common locations and [`include`](http://www.nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) it into your `server`s.

Comment: you make a good point. Do you know of any way to do this globally? I.e. for all server blocks - without having to be explicit at the server level

Answer (score 4):

Complementing Dayo answer, we must also add a trailing dollar, otherwise any file like `jquery.mousescroller.js` will also be blocked.

```
location ~ (\.php$|myadmin) {
    return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an also try `if` and regex. E.g. for servering static files with exclusion rules, I did it as below, to serve debug js files from a different folder tree. :

```
location /some/virtual/path/ {
    if( $request_uri !~ '\.js$' ) { return 404 ; }
    alias /some/real/path/
}
```